# Need help to deny S3 bucket creation without specific Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM policy to only allow the "Test" user to create S3 bucket with "Name" and "Bucket" Tags while creating. But not able to do.

I have tried this, but even with the specified condition, the user is not able to create an Bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:CreateBucket",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Name": "Bucket"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) documentation page lists the conditions that can be applied to the `CreateBucket` command.

Tags are *not* included in this list. Therefore, it is not possible to restrict the `CreateBucket` command based on tags being specified with the command.

Comment: Ok, But how can I make sure that a particular resource should be tagged to some value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

@pop I believe you can't do this using an IAM policy nor an SCP because by design S3 create tag API is configured to be triggered as a subsequent call to CreateBucket API. So your IAM policy would prevent creation of S3 Bucket itself even if you have added this tag. This is by design for S3 service compared to other AWS services.

Only option in my opinion would be a post-deployment action i.e. to choose an event driven model where you use S3 events to take actions (delete bucket/ add access block bucket policy etc.) based on how a bucket got created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Understood now, Thanks Manu.

Answer (score 0):

As John Rotenstein pointed out, this is not possibly (yet at least) to explicitly deny this but there are a few options that people do for this since this type of tagging policy is a common things in many organizations.

#### Compliance Reports

You can use the [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) service to detect S3 bucket resources that are out-of-compliance.  You can define your [tagging policy for S3 Buckets with a Config rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html).

This will not prevent users from creating buckets but it will provide a way to audit your accounts and also be proactively notified.

#### Auto-remediation

If you want a bucket to be auto-deleted or flagged, you can create a lambda function that is [triggered by the CloudTrail API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html) for when buckets are created.

The Lambda could be implemented to check the tags and, if the bucket is non-compliant, try and delete the bucket or mark it for deletion via some other process you define.

Comment: Ok, But how can I make sure that a particular resource should be tagged to some value. Is this possible, without lambda?

Comment: @pop JD's answer explains this. The only other way is to **prohibit users from creating buckets** and require them to **use your own bucket-creation service** to create buckets. They would somehow 'call' your service, which would create the requested bucket in their behalf with the required tags.